# Horizontal Pie Chart or Capsule chart Android

Tags: android, xml, charts, android-widget

[image]

I want to display 3 phases as you can see in image with different color.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create horizontal pie chart using below code.

You can give percentage to row of table.

TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
 TableRow.LayoutParams params1 = new   TableRow.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 10f);
        row.setLayoutParams(params1);
        row.setPadding(50, 10, 50, 10);
       // row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#22000000"));

```
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params2 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, 110, 50f);
    tv.setLayoutParams(params2);
    tv.setTextSize(30);
    tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_chart);
   // tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#659D32"));

    TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params3 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 10f);
    tv2.setLayoutParams(params3);
    tv2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffff19"));

    TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
    TableRow.LayoutParams params4 = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 40f);
    tv3.setLayoutParams(params4);
    tv3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_chart);
    //tv3.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));

    row.addView(tv);
    row.addView(tv2);
    row.addView(tv3);
```

By using this code you will get exact chart like shown in image.